# Can we detect presence of a 'Chart' in a report for using <analytics:reportCharts> component?

Tags: apex, visualforce, report-chart, analytics-api

When using the component I'm receiving following error due to a chart not present in the report, be cause I verified Report exists and is public shared and report types are valid (Summary/Matrix), which are allowed Formats:

> You can't view the report chart because its report, report type, or
>   chart has been deleted.

So my query is, can we detect programatically, in Apex, if Report has an embedded chart in it?

Comment: you can use metadata API to check if report has a chart or not.

Comment: I would like to remain in context of visualforce and apex only. I'm looking through Analytics APi docs but could not find anything regarding chart detection.

Comment: yes that is under the context of apex because this information is not available from Analytics API. Let me grab sample code for that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to show a chart if there's a chart on the report, otherwise you don't want to show anything (not even the error).

If that's the case you can use the attribute **hideOnError** on the `analytics:reportChart` component

if you set this attribute to true, if the report doesn't have a chart, then you won't see the error.

Comment: Yes I know, but that only hides the chart but leave the canvas space displayed as blank white space box. For example, if we do multiple `analytics:reportChart`  in a `repeat` tag then with this setting turn on if chart at index #2 fails, then there will be a blank space between chart #1 and chart #3, which is also not ideal.

Comment: you can use JS / jQuery to hide the blocks with no charts..

Comment: Yes good idea, though, we'll need a callback interface on charts to make sure our JS function fire after charts component have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

[**Salesforce from Metadata API**](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) can be used to detect if report contains any chart or not. here is sample piece of code  I am sharing which can give you a head start.

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();


String[] reportNames = new String[]{};

//query the report
Report r : [Select OwnerId,NamespacePrefix,Name, Id, DeveloperName, Description 
                                From Report where Id =:'YOUR REPORT id']
reportName = 'unfiled$public'+'/' + r.DeveloperName; 
//add to report list so that multiple report data can be fetched.
reportNames.add(reportName);

for(MetadataService.Metadata reportData :  service.readMetadata('Report',reportNames).getRecords())
{
    MetadataService.Report reportData1 = (MetadataService.Report)reportData;
    if(reportIdName.containsKey(reportData1.fullName) && reportData1.chart != null){
            //CHART AVAILABLE
    }
    else
    {
        //chart not available
    }

}
```

Comment: thnx for this, but wouldn't using metadata api require to setup an EndPoint to self-organization? Which will require manual setup because we can't work that out in managed package installer?

Comment: yes you need to setup EndPoint. but you can also create that using apex. (google it and you will find the solution for that.)

Comment: yes I know about that, but that is kind of a hack, and salesforce's security review team will not pass that :-)